# Process Maker Designer Issues

Tags: processmaker, processmaker-api

I recently installed process maker 3.8 community edition. I am unable to create any workflows since I cant drag object to the workspace and the variable etc throw an error as shown in the images below.

workspace

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are not installing a more recent version such as the ProcessMaker Spring release (4.6.2)?  It is significantly more powerful than 3.8.